# Вопрос про наследование

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, переопределение

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B(6);
    }

    public static class A {
        private int f1 = 7;

        public A(int f1) {
            this.f1 = f1;
            initialize();
        }

        protected void initialize() {
            System.out.println(f1);
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        protected int f1 = 3;

        public B(int f1) {
            super(f1);
            this.f1 += f1;
            initialize();
        }

        protected void initialize() {
            System.out.println(f1);
        }
    }
}
```

Здравствуйте, код выдает 0 9. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему если поменять модификатор метода initialize() в классе А на private, то получаем 6 9 ? Инициализация все равно же начинается с класса-родителя. Как меняется механизм?

Comment: станет понятнее если добавить [вывод  в метод Initialize](https://ideone.com/oC2dpK) - в случае protected, вызывается переопределенный потомком метод, и так как в момент вызова поля потомка еще не инициализированы - выводится 0, в случае private - вызывается метод базового класса

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Как здесь [сказать спасибо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

> Конструкторы класса не должны вызывать переопределяемые методы,
> непосредственно или опосредованно. Нарушение этого правила может
> привести к аварийному завершению программы. Конструктор суперкласса
> выполняется прежде конструктора подкласса, а потому переопределяющий
> метод в подклассе будет вызываться перед запуском конструктора этого
> подкласса. И если переопределенный метод зависит от инициализации,
> которую осуществляет конструктор подкласса, то этот метод будет
> работать совсем не так, как ожидалось.
>
> Дж.Блох, Эффективное программирование на Java

именно это Ваш код и делает - вызывает переопределяемый метод в конструкторе суперкласса. В результате вызывается метод наследника, что никак не ожидаемо. При объявлении же метода как private наследования как такового не происходит, в субклассе создается метод, совпадающий по сигнатуре и имени с приватным методом суперкласса и конструкторы теперь "стучатся" к методам своих классов.

Comment: Премного благодарен!